# Interaction between UpdateView, ModelForm and URL

Tags: python, django-forms, modelform, updateview

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I am trying to create a view in which it will be possible to update information about the model object. I do this using UpdateView and ModelForm.

Here is the form that inherits objects from the model

```
class UpdateOrderDir(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = m.OrderStorage
        fields = '__all__'
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

View

```
class DetailOrderViewDir(UpdateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('directorOrdersDetail')
    template_name = "director/order_detail_dir.html"
    form_class = f.UpdateOrderDir

    def get_queryset(self):
        return m.OrderStorage.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

URL

```
path('director/orders/<int:pk>/', v.DetailOrderViewDir.as_view(), name='directorOrdersDetail'),
```

At the output I get a form.

[image]

When I make changes to the Form, the following error occurs, but the data is updated.

[image]

So that when submitting the form, the page is updated and the user is on the same page

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by passing success_url through a function.

```
    def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('directorOrdersDetail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']}
```